# Is showing that if two vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are linearly independent, then they span $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra

For example, if you show that

$c_1 = c_2 = 0$

is the only solution to

$c_1\textbf{v}_1 + c_2\textbf{v}_2 = \textbf{0}$

Then you've shown that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent and span $\mathbb{R}^n$ right?

Comment: No. Let $n = 3, \mathbf{v}_1 = (1, 0, 0), \mathbf{v}_2 = (0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: spanning means that each vector in the vector space can be represented as a linear combination of the vectors in the spanning set.

Comment: Not unless $n=2$. The $n$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ (also) stands for the number of linearly independent vectors needed to span the entire space.

Comment: @okmanl You're going to want to look up the definition of [span](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_span).  You don't seem to have it right.

Answer (score 1):

No. Two vectors linearly independents only span $\mathbb R^{2}$. But, if $n>2$, two vectors linearly independents can only span a subset of $\mathbb R^{n}$ because its basis has the same number of elements than its dimension.

Answer (score 1):

No, all that shows is that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ is linearly independent. In order to show that a set $S$ spans a  vector space $V$, you need to show that *any* vector $v\in V$ can be written as a linear combination of elements of $S$: $$v=a_1s_1+a_2s_2+...+a_ns_n, \quad s_1,s_2, . . . , s_n\in S.$$ There are linearly independent sets that don't span (like $\{(0,0, 1), (0, 1, 0)\}$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$) and spanning sets that aren't linearly independent (like $\mathbb{R}^3$ in $\mathbb{R}^3$).

Comment: Ok, but since I'm only doing vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$, then I just need to show that $c_1 = c_2 = 0$ is the only solution to $c_1v_1 + c_2v_2 = 0$, right?

Comment: @okmanl In $\mathbb{R}^2$, yes, an two-element linearly independent set is also spanning.

Answer (score 0):

With only two vectors in $$\mathbb{R}^3$$ you can spann a plane if the vectors are linearly independent  or a line if they are parallel or a point if both of them are the zero vector.

You need n linearly independent vectors to spann $$\mathbb{R}^n$$

Answer (score 0):

No. The reason is that no set of fewer vectors than the dimension of the vector space can be a spanning set for the vector space, just like no spanning set of vectors more than the dimension of the vector space can be linearly independent.